# APNS quiet hours

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to decide which way to implement a "quiet hours" feature in my app to allow users to specify times in which push notifications should be silent.  I see two options:

1) Server-side. Their settings are sent to the server which sends notifications with different properties (or perhaps not at all) during quiet hours.

2) Client-side. The app receives all notifications via silent push, the app then processes each notification and only notifies the user as appropriate.

I see problems / limitations with each method.

For #1, the implementation becomes more complex (especially if I want to add additional notification filters based on alert type, etc), and the issue of which timezone the client is in would be very hard to resolve (especially as the client moves from one timezone to another). I certainly don't want to be tracking their position and updating their current timezone on the server.

For #2 I have read a number of comments in various places that the silent push that goes only to the app is not as reliable as normal push notifications that directly notify the user and are not processed through the app. I would prefer to implement quiet hours in this way, but I am very concerned about a reduction in the reliability of the notifications coming through. I have also read that the app will NOT be started in the background if the user has force-quit it. Is that still the case?

I have two questions. First, how have others handled this concept of quiet hours? Second, is the silent push as unreliable as I have heard in the real-world, or has this gotten better (or worse) with the latest versions of iOS? I know there are factors, such as how much power the app consumes while processing these notifications. On average my app would only receive a few silent notifications a day, and processing would be very fast.

Comment: Have a look at notification extensions. An extension allows the notification to execute some code and do something independently of the app just before it gets presented to the user, though I can't remember if that includes the ability to alter the sound or not. (there are two types of extension, service extension and content extension).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is really an answer, but too much for a comment!

Is your app likely to be used in different time zones?

Or are your users all based in one country?

This could mean handling client side is going to be a lot simpler.

Also remember that there is no guaranteed delivery time of a push, its normally pretty instant, but not always, so although you might of sent it with 5 minutes to spare before a quiet hour, it might arrive after the quiet hour has actually started.

Comment: The app will definitely be used across multiple timezones. This would be easy to support client-side, as the device itself already handles that. The quiet-hours would simply compare against the "current" time as reported by the device. That is one reason I prefer implementing it using method #2.